# MYSQL, in a query how to add two conditions with different value?

Tags: mysql, select

I have table of name datas (just an example data)

[image]

I want the min(published_time), max(published_time) and datatype and it should be group by datatype.
For datatype (AUDIO, VIDEO, BOOKS) the datastate should be "ACTIVE", and for others datastate can be anything.
I tried

```
select min(published_time),max(published_time),datatype,datastate from datas where ((datatype = 'AUDIO' or datatype= 'VIDEO' or datatype= 'BOOKS') and datastate = 'ACTIVE') or datastate != 'ACTIVE';
```

But I did not get the expected answer.
How can I achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions can be simplified to:

```
WHERE datastate = 'ACTIVE' OR datatype NOT IN ('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'BOOKS')
```

and you must use `GROUP BY datatype` in your query:

```
SELECT MIN(published_time), MAX(published_time), datatype
FROM datas
WHERE datastate = 'ACTIVE' OR datatype NOT IN ('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'BOOKS')
GROUP BY datatype
```

The column `datastate` does not make sense in the results because it can be anything in case `datatype` is not any of `'AUDIO'`, `'VIDEO'` or `'BOOKS'`.
If you want all the `datastate`s of each `datatype` you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT MIN(published_time), MAX(published_time), datatype,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT datastate) datastates
FROM datas
WHERE datastate = 'ACTIVE' OR datatype NOT IN ('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'BOOKS')
GROUP BY datatype
```

Comment: can also get the min(published_time) and max(published_time) along with its  *ID*? if not can you tell me why?

Comment: These are 2 ids: 1 for the min(published_time) and 1 for the max(published_time) for each datatype and you will need 2 joins to the table. This can be done only if the column published_time is unique for each datatype. Do you want it?

Comment: No but thank you for replaying. I used two different query to get min and max of publish_time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `where` clause you want is:

```
where 
    (datatype in ('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'BOOKS') and datastate = 'ACTIVE') 
    or datatype not in ('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'BOOKS')
```

As for the entire query, it is not that clear which result you want. I understand that you want to aggregate by `datatype`, so that should be something like:

```
select min(published_time), max(published_time), datatype, any_value(datastate) datastate
from datas
    where 
        (datatype in ('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'BOOKS') and datastate = 'ACTIVE') 
        or datatype not in ('AUDIO', 'VIDEO', 'BOOKS') 
group by datatype
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but didn't get the proper answer, it may work for the about table data but not for others.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
min(publish_time), max(publish_time), datatype 
FROM `datas` 
WHERE 
((datatype='AUDIO' OR datatype='VIDEO' OR datatype='BOOKS') AND datastate='ACTIVE') OR (datatype!='AUDIO' AND datatype!='VIDEO' AND datatype!='BOOKS')
GROUP BY datatype
```